# Spring 5 web application cannot find login.html

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am lead developer on an old Spring 4 web application, and we are being forced to upgrade to Spring 5 due to insecurities in Spring Security 4.  I have absolutely no experience configuring Spring applications, as I've been fortunate enough to join mature developer teams where the application is in production, but the current team is responsible for bug fixes and enhancements.  So I'm working mostly in the dark here.

I've gotten past all the compile and startup errors, but Spring is unable to find my login page.  Here's my configuration:

security.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<b:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
         xmlns:b="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans https://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security https://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-5.8.xsd"
         default-lazy-init="true">
    
    <http auto-config="false"
        entry-point-ref="authenticationProcessingFilterEntryPoint"
        create-session="ifRequired" use-expressions="true">

        <intercept-url 
            pattern='/scripts/**'
            access='permitAll' />
        <intercept-url 
            pattern='/styles/**'
            access='permitAll' />
        <intercept-url 
            pattern='/common/**'
            access='permitAll' />
        <intercept-url 
            pattern='/images/**'
            access='permitAll' />
        <intercept-url 
            pattern='/**/welcome.html*'
            access="hasRole('ROLE_AUTHENTICATED')" />
        <intercept-url 
            pattern='/**/login.html*'
            access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url 
            pattern='/**/exception.html'
            access="hasRole('ROLE_CONTENT_MGR')" />

<!-- I have removed hundreds of lines of intercept-url markup, leaving the ones that I think matter -->

        <custom-filter position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="combinedAuthenticationProcessingFilter" />
        <custom-filter position="CONCURRENT_SESSION_FILTER" ref="concurrencyFilter" />
        <logout logout-url="/logout.html"
            logout-success-url="/finish.html" invalidate-session="true"
            delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" />
        <access-denied-handler ref="denied" />
        <headers>
            <frame-options policy="SAMEORIGIN" />
        </headers>
    </http>

    <global-method-security
        secured-annotations="enabled" pre-post-annotations="enabled" />

    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider
            ref="combinedAuthenticationProvider" >
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
    
    <b:bean id="denied"
        class=" blah.blahblah.app.web.security.AppAccessDeniedHandler">
        <b:property name="errorPage" value="/denied.html" />
    </b:bean>
    
    <b:bean id="combinedAuthenticationProcessingFilter"
        class="blah.blahblah.app.web.security.CombinedAuthenticationProcessingFilter">
        <b:constructor-arg value="/j_security_check" />
        <b:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
        <b:property name="authenticationFailureHandler" ref="failureHandler" />
        <b:property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="successHandler" />
        <b:property name="filterProcessesUrl" value="/j_security_check" />
        <b:property name="authenticationDetailsSource" ref="iamUserDetailsSource" />
        <b:property name="sessionAuthenticationStrategy" ref="sas" />
    </b:bean>

    <b:bean id="iamUserDetailsSource" class="blah.blahblah.app.web.security.IAMAuthenticationDetailsSource"></b:bean>

    <b:bean id="concurrencyFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter">
        <b:constructor-arg ref="sessionRegistry" />
        <b:constructor-arg value="/login.html" />
    </b:bean>

    <b:bean id="successHandler" class="blah.blahblah.app.web.security.AuthenticationSuccessHandler">
        <b:property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/welcome.html" />
        <!-- <property name="useReferer" value="true"/> -->
    </b:bean>

    <b:bean id="failureHandler"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler">
        <b:constructor-arg value="/login.html?error=true" />
    </b:bean>

    <b:bean id="authenticationProcessingFilterEntryPoint"
        class=" org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <!-- Redirect to tester.html to determine Javascript capability -->
        <b:constructor-arg value="/login.html" />
        <b:property name="forceHttps" value="false" />
    </b:bean>

    <b:bean id="combinedAuthenticationProvider" class="blah.blahblah.app.web.security.CombinedAuthenticationProvider">
        <b:property name="accountLookupService" ref="accountLookupService" />
    </b:bean>

    <!-- <bean id="anonymousAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.providers.anonymous.AnonymousAuthenticationProvider">
        <property name="key" value="anonymous"/> </bean> -->
    <!-- This bean definition must be available to ApplicationContext.getBean()
        so StartupListener can look for it and detect if password encryption is turned
        on or not -->
    <!-- <bean id="passwordEncoder" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.ShaPasswordEncoder"/> -->

    <!-- This bean is optional; it isn't used by any other bean as it only listens
        and logs -->
    <b:bean id="loggerListener"
        class="org.springframework.security.authentication.event.LoggerListener" />

    <!-- sessionRegistry provides access to active security principals. -->
    <b:bean id="sessionRegistry"
        class="org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl" />

    <b:bean id="sas"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy">
        <b:constructor-arg>
            <b:list>
                <b:bean
                    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy">
                    <b:constructor-arg ref="sessionRegistry" />
                    <b:property name="maximumSessions" value="-1" />
                    <b:property name="exceptionIfMaximumExceeded" value="false" />
                </b:bean>
                <b:bean
                    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.SessionFixationProtectionStrategy">
                </b:bean>
                <b:bean
                    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy">
                    <b:constructor-arg ref="sessionRegistry" />
                </b:bean>
            </b:list>
        </b:constructor-arg>
    </b:bean>
</b:beans>
```

spring-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
 
    <context:component-scan base-package="blah.blahblah.app.web" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/scripts/**" location="/scripts/" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/styles/default/**" location="/styles/default/" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/common/**" location="/common/" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/decorators/**" location="/decorators/" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/images/**" location="/images/" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
     
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <mvc:interceptors>
         <bean class="blah.blahblah.app.web.interceptor.AppRedirectInterceptor"></bean>
     </mvc:interceptors> 
     
</beans>
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
    <display-name>Spring5 Web Application</display-name>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>defaultHtmlEscape</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>
                /WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml
                /WEB-INF/security.xml
                /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml            
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>net.sf.navigator.menu.MenuContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>MultipartFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MultipartFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>MultipartFilter</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>/*</servlet-name>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/j_security_check</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>encoding-filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>encoding-filter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.filter.PageFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>CsrfCheckFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>blah.blahblah.app.web.filter.CsrfCheckFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CsrfCheckFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

applicationContext.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.2.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-4.2.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.2.xsd"
            
    default-lazy-init="true">

    <context:annotation-config/>
    
    <bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver" > 
        <!-- setting maximum upload size -->
        <property name="maxUploadSize" value="10000000" />
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="utf-8" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="buildInfo" class="blah.blahblah.app.util.BuildInfo" lazy-init="false">
        <property name="buildProperties" ref="buildProperties"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="configuration" class="blah.blahblah.app.util.Configuration" lazy-init="false">
        <property name="servletContextAttributeKey" value="configuration"/>
        <property name="buildInfo" ref="buildInfo"/>
    </bean>

    <util:properties id="buildProperties" location="classpath:buildInfo.properties" scope="singleton"/>

<!-- a bunch of bean definitions that I don't think are relevant to this issue -->

    <import resource="classpath:/applicationContext-resources.xml"/>
    <import resource="classpath:/applicationContext-dao.xml"/>
    <import resource="classpath:/applicationContext-service.xml"/>
    <import resource="classpath:/applicationContext-messages.xml"/>
    <import resource="classpath:/applicationContext-aop.xml"/>
</beans>
```

login.jsp

```
<%@ include file="/common/taglibs.jsp" %>
<%@ page import="org.springframework.web.servlet.support.ServletUriComponentsBuilder" %>
<%
    // If the IAM header that identified the user is present, just redirect to
    // j_security_check and the authentication filter will do the login.
    if (request.getHeader("uid") != null) {
        String url = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentContextPath().path("/j_security_check").build().encode().toUri().toString();
        System.out.println("login.jsp...redirect to " + url +" with uid "+ request.getHeader("uid"));    
        response.sendRedirect(url);
    }
%>
<spring:url var="jQueryCookieUrl" value="/scripts/jquery.cookie.js">
    <spring:param name="r" value="#attr.configuration.buildInfo.revision"/>
</spring:url>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta name="heading" content="<spring:message code="login.header"/>"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<spring:url value="/scripts/jquery-1.4.2.js"/>"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="${jQueryCookieUrl}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

            if (!jQuery.cookie('javaScriptEnabled')) {
                jQuery.cookie('javaScriptEnabled', 'true');
            }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="document.loginForm.j_username.focus();">

<%--
NOTE: The only Spring Security Exception that should redirect to this page is BadCredentialsException. The other
      exceptions are displayed by authFailure.jsp.
--%>
<c:if test="${param.error != null}"><spring:message code="login.authenticationErrorMsg"/></c:if>
<c:if test="${param.logout != null}"><spring:message code="login.userLoggedOutMsg"/></c:if>
<form method="post" id="loginForm" name="loginForm" action="<c:url value='/j_security_check'/>">
    <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>
    <fieldset class="two-column natural-width">
        <div class="app-group" id="appgrp_j_username">
            <div class="app-label" id="applbl_j_username">
                <label class="desc" for="j_username"><span class="required"><img alt="required field" title="required field" src="/app-system-web/images/required.png"></span>        
                &nbsp;&nbsp;<fmt:message key="login.userName"/>:
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="app-control app-input" id="appctrl_j_username">
                <input type="text" id="j_username" tabindex="1" value="" name="j_username">
            </div>
        </div>
            <div class="app-group" id="appgrp_j_password">
            <div class="app-label" id="applbl_j_password">
                <label class="desc" for="j_password"><span class="required"><img alt="required field" title="required field" src="/app-system-web/images/required.png"></span>        
                &nbsp;&nbsp;<fmt:message key="login.password"/>: 
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="app-control app-input" id="appctrl_j_password">        
                <input type="password" id="j_password" tabindex="2" name="j_password">
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="buttons">
        <div class="app-group" id="appgrp_login_button">
            <div class="app-control app-button" id="appctrl_login_button">
                <input type="submit" tabindex="3" value="Submit" name="login.submitButtonText" id="login_button">
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

LoginLogoutController.java

```
package blah.blahblah.app.web.account;

// imports removed 

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/")
public class LoginLogoutController extends AppControllerBase {
    
    private static final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(LoginLogoutController.class);
    
    @Autowired
    private AnnouncementService announcementService;
    private List<Announcement> announcements;
    
    @Autowired
    private Auditor auditor;
    
    @RequestMapping(value="/login", method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST})
    public String login(@RequestParam(value="error", required = false) String error, Model model) {
        if (error != null) {
            model.addAttribute("error", "true");
        }
        return"login";
    }
 
    @RequestMapping(value = "/logout", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String logout() {
        //getSession().invalidate();
        ServletRequestAttributes attr = (ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes();
        LOG.debug("getRemoteUser " + attr.getRequest().getRemoteUser());
        return "redirect:/finish.html";
    }
    
    @RequestMapping(value = "/finish", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String finish(HttpServletRequest request, HttpSession session) {
        SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
        session.invalidate();
        ServletRequestAttributes attr = (ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes();
        LOG.debug("getRemoteUser " + attr.getRequest().getRemoteUser());
        return "finish";
    }
    
    @RequestMapping(value = "/welcome", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_AUTHENTICATED')")
    public String welcome(ModelMap model) {
        AnnouncementFilter filter = new AnnouncementFilter();
        filter.setIncludeNew(true);
        announcements = announcementService.search(filter);
        List<AuditInfo> auditInfoList = new ArrayList<AuditInfo>();
        List<Announcement> encodedHtml = new ArrayList<Announcement>();
        for (Announcement announcement : announcements) {
            auditInfoList.add(auditor.getAuditInfo(announcement));
            announcement.setBody(getEscapedString(announcement.getBody()));
            encodedHtml.add(announcement);
        }
        model.addAttribute("announcements", encodedHtml);
        model.addAttribute("auditInfoList", auditInfoList);
        ServletRequestAttributes attr = (ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes();
        LOG.debug("ServletRequestAttributes: " + attr.toString());
        return "welcome";
    }
    
    @RequestMapping(value = "/contact", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String contact() {
        return "contact";
    }
    
    @RequestMapping(value = "/authFailure", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String authFailure() {
        return "authFailure";
    }
    
    @RequestMapping(value = "/denied", method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST})
    public String denied() {
        return "403";
    }
}
```

I have put the Spring packages in TRACE mode to see if I can glean anything from the application logs.  Here are what I think are the most important lines from the application log:

```
.
.
.
DispatcherServlet.initServletBean(547) | Completed initialization in 111410 ms
DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBean(264) | Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.security.filterChainProxy'
FilterChainProxy.getFilters(237) | Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=any request, Filters=[org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@66c5e5a2, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@2b673939, org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter@5bc5531b, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@24b80905, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@3e8e0a50, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@6b7cbb60, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@3a2a7509, blah.blahblah.app.web.security.CombinedAuthenticationProcessingFilter@a583c30, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@7a2227b8, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@9f64299, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@18bac23f, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@2ad68e1a, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@72fb5f9b, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@750539cd]] (1/1)
FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(222) | Securing GET /login.html
FilterChainProxy.doFilter(358) | Invoking DisableEncodeUrlFilter (1/14)
FilterChainProxy.doFilter(358) | Invoking SecurityContextPersistenceFilter (2/14)
HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.readSecurityContextFromSession(207) | No HttpSession currently exists
HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.loadContext(129) | Created SecurityContextImpl [Null authentication]
SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(109) | Set SecurityContextHolder to empty SecurityContext
FilterChainProxy.doFilter(358) | Invoking ConcurrentSessionFilter (3/14)
FilterChainProxy.doFilter(358) | Invoking WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter (4/14)
FilterChainProxy.doFilter(358) | Invoking HeaderWriterFilter (5/14)
FilterChainProxy.doFilter(358) | Invoking CsrfFilter (6/14)
CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(115) | Did not protect against CSRF since request did not match CsrfNotRequired [TRACE, HEAD, GET, OPTIONS]
FilterChainProxy.doFilter(358) | Invoking LogoutFilter (7/14)
LogoutFilter.requiresLogout(121) | Did not match request to Ant [pattern='/logout.html', POST]
FilterChainProxy.doFilter(358) | Invoking CombinedAuthenticationProcessingFilter (8/14)
FilterChainProxy.doFilter(358) | Invoking RequestCacheAwareFilter (9/14)
HttpSessionRequestCache.getMatchingRequest(112) | No saved request
FilterChainProxy.doFilter(358) | Invoking SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter (10/14)
FilterChainProxy.doFilter(358) | Invoking AnonymousAuthenticationFilter (11/14)
FilterChainProxy.doFilter(358) | Invoking SessionManagementFilter (12/14)
AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.defaultWithAnonymous(116) | Set SecurityContextHolder to AnonymousAuthenticationToken [Principal=anonymousUser, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]]
SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(121) | Request requested invalid session id 3C223782CCE18B60ED81F83C8D8FA838
FilterChainProxy.doFilter(358) | Invoking ExceptionTranslationFilter (13/14)
FilterChainProxy.doFilter(358) | Invoking FilterSecurityInterceptor (14/14)
ExpressionBasedFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource.getAttributes(89) | Did not match request to Ant [pattern='/scripts/**'] - [permitAll] (1/366)
ExpressionBasedFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource.getAttributes(89) | Did not match request to Ant [pattern='/styles/**'] - [permitAll] (2/366)
ExpressionBasedFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource.getAttributes(89) | Did not match request to Ant [pattern='/common/**'] - [permitAll] (3/366)
ExpressionBasedFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource.getAttributes(89) | Did not match request to Ant [pattern='/images/**'] - [permitAll] (4/366)
ExpressionBasedFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource.getAttributes(89) | Did not match request to Ant [pattern='/**/welcome.html*'] - [hasRole('ROLE_AUTHENTICATED')] (5/366)
FilterSecurityInterceptor.authenticateIfRequired(325) | Did not re-authenticate AnonymousAuthenticationToken [Principal=anonymousUser, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]] before authorizing
FilterSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(219) | Authorizing filter invocation [GET /login.html] with attributes [permitAll]
FilterSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(224) | Authorized filter invocation [GET /login.html] with attributes [permitAll]
FilterSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(244) | Did not switch RunAs authentication since RunAsManager returned null
FilterChainProxy.doFilter(348) | Secured GET /login.html
HttpSessionEventPublisher.extracted(85) | Publishing event: org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionCreatedEvent[source=org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@777d69ee]
DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBean(264) | Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'sessionRegistry'
CsrfCheckFilter.doFilter(38) | Validating referrer and origin...
DispatcherServlet.traceDebug(117) | GET "/app-system-web/login.html", parameters={}, headers={masked} in DispatcherServlet 'spring'
**PageNotFound.noHandlerFound(1283) | No mapping for GET /app-system-web/login.html**
HstsHeaderWriter.writeHeaders(152) | Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match request to [Is Secure]
HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.saveContext(417) | Did not store anonymous SecurityContext
DispatcherServlet.logResult(1131) | Completed 404 NOT_FOUND, headers={masked}
HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.saveContext(417) | Did not store anonymous SecurityContext
SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(125) | Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request
```

And, of course, when I try to go to the login page, I get the following:
[image: 404 Error]

Essentially, my application cannot find my login page.  I have tried a number of things that have not worked, and I am completely at a loss. If anyone has the guts to wade through all the configuration posted above and give me some hints as to what I've got wrong, I'd be eternally grateful!

Comment: you have the following message in your error stack trace `**PageNotFound.noHandlerFound(1283) | No mapping for GET /app-system-web/login.html`. Just doing a search in the config you posted, I can't see `/app-system-web/` as a path. Is that ok? Maybe I'm missing something

Answer (score 0):

After some research, if I make this change (I added **.html** to the request mapping URL):

```java
    @RequestMapping(value = "/login.html", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String login(@RequestParam(value="error", required=false) String error, Model model) {
        if (error != null) {
            model.addAttribute("error","true");
        }
        return"login";
    }
```

I can get to the login page. What I don't understand is why the '.html' is required.